# Enable echo after the whole for was executed in cmd

Tags: cmd, echo, command-prompt

The current directory is `C:\`.

If I run

```
for /L %i in (1,1,3) do cd
```

- I get the following output:

  ```
  C:\>cd
  C:\

  C:\>cd
  C:\

  C:\>cd
  C:\
  ```

---

If I run

```
echo off && for /L %i in (1,1,3) do cd && echo on
```

- I get the following output:

  ```
  C:\

  C:\>cd   && echo on
  C:\

  C:\>cd   && echo on
  C:\
  ```

  (the `echo off` was applied only for the first iteration)

---

If I run

```
echo off && for /L %i in (1,1,3) do cd
```

- I get the following output:

  ```
  C:\
  C:\
  C:\
  ```

  which is fine, but the user has to type `echo on` to have a command prompt back (and this is not ok).

---

I don't want to get the prompt until the last command from `for ... do` was executed. But after that, I want to have the command prompt back.

How can I get the following output (the empty lines are not relevant), returning the command prompt at the end?

```
C:\

C:\

C:\
```

I want a solution that works in **cmd** (without PowerShell), not in a batch file.

Comment: Just a quick note on what is happening. You say that "the echo off was applied only for the first iteration". Well, of course it does, it's before the loop. The important point here is that `do cd && echo on` is treated as a single command and executed every time. I don't think there's a way an in-line for lop can behave any differently.

Comment: @SiHa , your comment helped me to found the straightforward solution below. Thanks!

Comment: Of course. So obvious now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I just have to use some parentheses for the `for` command, so that `echo on` will be executed only after the loop:

```
echo off && (for /L %i in (1,1,3) do cd) && echo on
```

Output:

```
C:\
C:\
C:\
```